# Securely storing refresh tokens, credentials in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, electron, native, gnome-keyring-daemon

I am building a native app for linux and all the back-end code is based on C++, i am able to connect to the server and obtain tokens from electron and currently storing it in a txt file.

What i need to achieve is to store refresh tokens along with few other user information securely on the system using C++ code from the backend. I will need to also fectch the information later in my code when token expires.I am aware that windows uses dpai for this and MAC uses Keychain. On googling enough, i found that gnome-keyring is one of the choices available when it comes to Linux.

I am unclear if gnome-keyring can be used to store these information securely and its support for C++. Wanted to know how these things are normally handled in Linux as i don't see any implementation online and any possible reference for implementing such functionality is much appreciated.